# How to share/include common files in several terraform projects

Tags: terraform

I have multiple terraform projects. Many of these projects have common files. Currently I am duplicating these files into the various projects. How can I share these files into the various projects.

Example: locator.tf

```
data "aws_subnet" "SubNet-0_1" {
  vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.VPC.id
  tags = {
    Name = "SubNet-0_1"
  }
}

data "aws_subnet" "SubNet-0_2" {
  vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.VPC.id
  tags = {
    Name = "SubNet-0_2"
  }
}
```

I have a copy of locator.tf file for each project. I want to have one file that is locator.tf. And then build the project to "include" locator.tf.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a [Terraform Module](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules) with the common code, then include that module in all your projects.

Comment: I tried that. However, it seems terraform treats modules as isolated. A resources described in module1 is not available in module2. ie I have a data resources in module2 common to all my projects, module1 has no visibility on the data resources. I want to share the data items across projects. It seems to me what is needed is some kind of "include" statement, probably in the module definition or more flexible as a resource definition.

Comment: Resources in modules don't have to be isolated. You simply need to define the values as outputs in the module, and then refer to those module outputs in your main Terraform code wherever you need to reference them. I know my answer isn't exactly what you are looking for, but this is the **only** thing that Terraform supports that is even remotely close to what you asked for.